# Unable to filter some value from table using angular.js

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, filter

i am using some Roman value(`i.e-I,II,III,......VIII`) in my table but when trying to filter table using these value for some value the filtration process is happening and for some value its not happening using angular.js. Please check my code below.

> subject.html:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="dataTable" >
<colgroup>
<col class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
<col class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
<col class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
<col class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
<col class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
<col class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
<col class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
</colgroup>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Sl. No</th>
<th>
<select style="width:100%; border:none; font-weight:bold;" ng-options="sub.name for sub in noCourse track by sub.value" ng-model="search" ng-change="selectedCourseTable();" >
<!-- <option value="">Course Name</option>-->
</select>
</th>
<th>
<select style="width:100%; border:none; font-weight:bold;" ng-options="sem.name for sem in noSemestersTable track by sem.value" ng-model="semesterSearch">
<option value="">Semester</option>
</select>
</th>
<th>Subject Name</th>
<th>Short Name</th>
<th>Edit</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody id="detailsstockid">
<tr ng-repeat="sub in subjectData | filter:{course_name:search.value, semester:semesterSearch.value }" >
<td>{{ $index+1 }}</td>
<td>{{sub.course_name}}</td>
<td>{{sub.semester}}</td>
<td>{{sub.subject_name}}</td>
<td >{{sub.short_name}}</td>
<td>
<a href='#subject?s_i={{sub.subject_id}}'>
<input type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-green' value='Edit'>  
</a>
</td>
</tr>   
</tbody>
</table>
```

For bind the data dynamically in table i have some db operation and inside the database the Roman values are also stored.Check my controller file.

> subjectController.js:

```
$http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: "php/subject/readCourse.php",
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        angular.forEach(response.data, function(obj){
            var Course={'name':obj.course_name , 'value':obj.course_name};
            $scope.noCourse.push(Course);
        });
    },function errorCallback(response) {

    });
$scope.selectedCourseTable=function(){
        if($scope.search.value=='Bachelor of Technology'){
            $scope.noSemestersTable=[
            {name:"I",value: "I"},
            {name:"II",value:"II"},
            {name:"III",value: "III"},
            {name:"IV",value: "IV"},
            {name:"V",value:"V"},
            {name:"VI",value: "VI"},
            {name:"VII",value:"VII"},
            {name:"VIII",value:"VIII"}
            ];
        }
        if($scope.search.value=='Master in Technology'){
            $scope.noSemestersTable=[
            {name:"I",value: "I"},
            {name:"II",value: "II"},
            {name:"III",value:"III"},
            {name:"IV",value:"IV"}
            ];
        }
        if($scope.search.value=='Master of computer application'){
            $scope.noSemestersTable=[
            {name:"I",value:"I"},
            {name:"II",value: "II"},
            {name:"III",value:"III"},
            {name:"IV",value:"IV"},
            {name:"V",value:"V"},
            {name:"VI",value:"VI"}
            ];
        }
        if($scope.search.value==''){
            $scope.noSemestersTable=null;
        }
    }
```

When i am selecting the value `III` onward the filtering is occurring properly  but when i am selecting `I or II` from drop down its not happening ,all values are showing.Actually i am confused about this issue for some value filter is working properly but for some value not working.Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Maybe you could show us exemplary entry from the `subjectData`?

Comment: @mic4ael : subjectData is an array which contains the db values.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the way how `filter` works. The match in the way you are using it right now is not strict. I think you should use `sub in subjectData | filter:{course_name:search.value, semester:semesterSearch.value }:true`.

Notice the `true` value at the end of the `filter` - this makes the comparison to be strict.

Comment: @ mic4ael : I applied your answer but when i added true as you added,the table value is not displaying at all initially but i am selecting only the selected filtering value is displaying.From the beginning all value should display and then user can filter.